# Absolute positioning being ignored on server

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to correct this for some time with no results. A fixed menu bar at the top of the page, working perfectly. Now trying to place a page title "Home Page" with absolute positioning is the top right of the menu bar works fine when I open it directly from my PC, but when I open it on my server the title appears below the menu and at the left of the page.

I've played around with fixed and relative positioning with relative again working when launched from my PC but with the same results on the server.

I hope I've provided enough of the right code but let me know.

Thank you for your suggestions and help.

```css
.fixed-menu
{
z-index:999;
position: fixed;
height: 10px;
width:inherit;
left:auto;
right:auto;
}

.page-title
{
position:absolute;
top:10;
right:10;
color:#000;
font-weight:600;
}

#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #001a00;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00FFFF 0%, #001a00 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #00FFFF), color-stop(100%, #001a00));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00FFFF 0%, #001a00 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00FFFF 0%, #001a00 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00FFFF 0%, #001a00 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00FFFF 0%, #001a00 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #9900FF;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

<div class="fixed-menu">
 <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Share with the Group</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li class='last'><a href='internet.html'><span>From the Internet</span></a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='athome.html'><span>From Your Computer</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='hide.html'><span>Hide Group in Timeline</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='nonotices'><span>Turn off Notifications</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='members.html'><span>Add Members</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='other.html'><span>Other</span></a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
   <div class="page-title">Home Page</div>
</div>

<div class="clear-menu"></div>

 <div id="banner">

  <div class="image"><img src="images/banner.jpg" width="900" height="349" title="Just for Laughs FB Group" border="0" /></div>
  <div class="title"><p>Just for Laughs</p></div>
 </div>
<!-- ********** Banner Table Ends ********** -->
<h1>Future Home of Just for Laughs FB Group</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Guys, the image in the link is NSFW. So be careful when you are clicking it.

Comment: For a start the positioning values of `..page-title` are unitless. **Validate!**

Comment: Sorry for that... I've replaced the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add px to the top and right definition of .page-title

```
.page-title
{
position:absolute;
top:10;
right:10;
color:#000;
font-weight:600;
}
```

Comment: Giving no unit only works for 0 but not for any other number ;)

Answer (score 1):

As I see here in `.page-title` selector, you have to use a unit to specify `top` and `right` values like for instance :

```
.page-title
{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:600;
}
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code as suggested with the same results. OK from PC, but still not working on the server.

Comment: Tried it again. And thank you that did in fact work.